# Stop WCF from binding to the model

Tags: c#, wcf, biztalk

I have a wcf soap service (yes I know, but I have no control over this)  and clients can send large messages to the wcf soap service.   Is it possible to stop wcf from binding to the model, in such a way that it still exposes the wsdl, and the objects schema, but I can just process the incoming stream instead of having wcf bind to the model and produce an instance of a very large object in memory?

What's actually happening in my case is we have a WCF service using BizTalk. We don't actually build the service, we just specify what request and response messages we want to receive and reply with, and the wcf binding and behaviours.  Biztalk has its wok web service host factory that somehow runs the service through IIS.  I don't know how that works.  The service itself is hosted in IIS, and received messages are committed to the BizTalk database.  Even very large messages do not have much of an impact on memory utilization, so I believe somehow the message is consumed as a stream.  We are looking to move the service away from BizTalk which means we need to retain the capability of receiving very large messages.  Typically you create a service contract, and the parameters of the service contract via an Interface, and the parameters of the interface functions specify what the soap request looks like.  The framework handles the creation of the wsdl, and when a request is received it deserializes the body of the soap request into instances of objects for you.  I want the wsdl to get published but I want to handle the request a stream, not as an instance of an object model.

Here's an example service with contracts and configuration.  I've tried to simplify for brevity.  Keep in mind I have no control over the request and response models.

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false,WrapperNamespace = "http://mynamespace")]
public class RequestMessage
{
    [MessageBodyMember()]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string HugeData{ get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false,WrapperNamespace = "http://mynamespace")]
public class ResponseMessage
{
    [MessageBodyMember()]
    public string response { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://mynamespace")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract()]
    ResponseMessage Submit(RequestMessage request);
}

[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://mynamespace")]
public class MyService: IMyService
{
    public ResponseMessage Submit(RequestMessage request)
    {
        //RequestMessage could be very large,  I don't want the asp.net framework to load it into an object instance.  I want to deal with it as a stream...
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

... 
    
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MyService">
            <endpoint name="Submit" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" contract="IMyService"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="MyBinding"  
                     closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                     openTimeout="00:01:00"
                     receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                     sendTimeout="00:01:00">
                
                <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64"
                                     maxWritePoolSize="16"
                                     messageVersion="Soap11"
                                     writeEncoding="utf-8">
                    <readerQuotas maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
                </textMessageEncoding>
                
                <security allowInsecureTransport="false"
                          allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="false"
                          authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
                          canRenewSecurityContextToken="true"
                          defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default"
                          enableUnsecuredResponse="false"
                          includeTimestamp="true"
                          keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy"
                          messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncryptAndEncryptSignature"
                          messageSecurityVersion="Default"
                          protectTokens="false"
                          requireDerivedKeys="true"
                          requireSecurityContextCancellation="true"
                          requireSignatureConfirmation="false"
                          securityHeaderLayout="Strict">                    
                </security>
                <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="false"
                                
                                allowCookies="false"
                                authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                                bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                                decompressionEnabled="true"
                                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                                keepAliveEnabled="true"
                                maxBufferSize="52428800"
                                maxPendingAccepts="0"
                                
                                proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                                
                                requestInitializationTimeout="00:00:00"
                                transferMode="Streamed"
                                unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                                useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                                
                                manualAddressing="false"
                                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    
                </httpsTransport>               
            
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
      
    <behaviors>     
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
            <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" 
                             httpsGetEnabled="true" 
                             policyVersion="Default"/>
            
            <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
            <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" 
                          httpsHelpPageEnabled="true"
                          includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

            <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Default"
                                  messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Failure"
                                  serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure"
                                  suppressAuditFailure="false"/>
            
            <!-- Enables the retrieval of metadata address information from the request message headers.  Causes the wsdl content to reference the address of the request instead of the netbios name of the machine. -->
            <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
                <defaultPorts>
                    <add scheme="http" port="80" />
                    <add scheme="https" port="443" />
                </defaultPorts>
            </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>

            <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="48"
                               maxConcurrentInstances="348"
                               maxConcurrentSessions="300"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    
    </behaviors>
      
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        <add binding="customBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
      
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
    
    ...

</configuration>
```

Comment: Some details would be nice... (like your `app.config`/`web.config`, your service interface and/or implementation outline, etc). What exactly constitutes a "large message" in this case? When you say "Incoming stream" do you mean you'd like to get a `Stream` for the request body? What about SOAP over other transports besides HTTP?

Comment: You can probably do some culling with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.soapattributes.soapignore?view=net-6.0).

Comment: @Dai -  The size that constitutes a large message probably isn't all that relevatn, but it could be 1gb for example.  Yes I would like to access as a stream object.  it has to be soap over http.

Comment: SOAP uses an XML envelope though - the way XML works (especially in WCF) pretty-much requires you to buffer the entire message somehow - so I'm not sure how a `Stream` access to the raw message body is going to help...

Comment: @Dai I'm assuming that, if you imagine a service implementation in c# you have something like myfunction(MyObject myobject).  In that case it will deserialize the body into a MyObject instance, all in memory.

Comment: @Jeremy Not necessarily - it entirely depends on your service configuration - which you haven't shared with us yet. Is your WCF code running within ASP.NET and/or IIS, or is it self-hosted? When WCF runs on top of ASP.NET I believe (though am not absolutely certain) that it uses ASP.NET's request buffering scheme which will buffer incoming requests to disk as the server-side .NET code reads through it.

Comment: Please share  more details. By stopping binding, you mean you don't need to specify binding, but there will still be a default binding.

Comment: @Dai - tried to add more detail and context